# R and GGPLO2: Factor variable to drive Color in Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Summary: In R, I want ggplot to align the color of geom_point based upon a factor variable within the dataframe.

Here is an example of the data:

```
#CREATE VECTORS
C1<-c(2,2,2,1,1,0,0)
C2<-c(1,1,2,1,0,0,1)
C3<-c("YELLOW", "YELLOW",   "GREEN","RED",  "RED",  "RED",  "RED")

#COMBINE VECTORS - CREATE DATAFRAME
x<- data.frame(cbind(C1,C2,C3))
```

Use ggplot to create plot:

```
ggplot(x, aes(C1,C2)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color=C3)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=C3))
```

[image]

I would like the C3 variable to choose the color in the plot, meaning GREEN=green, RED=red, and YELLOW = yellow

Comment: You should encode the colour scheme using scale_colour_manual: `... + scale_colour_manual(values = c("GREEN" = "green", "RED" = "red", "YELLOW" = "yellow"))`

Comment: This is probably just a toy example, but in general, don't use color names in your data to map to colors in your plot. Use meaningful labels that correspond to groups in your data, and keep the actual color values as just an implementation detail in your visualization's color scale. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46625522/matching-legend-items-and-colours-in-ggplot2-where-some-geom-segment-are-not-inc/46625784#46625784) for more.

Comment: Andrew Milligan: Thank you for your response, your solution worked.  You are correct this is a "toy example".  I spelled out "YELLOW" = "yellow" just to make sure I got my point across.  I see from bergant response is more to what I was looking for in that the color in the plot is completely dependent upon the values in C3: color = C3.  Again, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

See [scale_color_identity](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_identity.html).
For example:

```
ggplot(x, aes(C1, C2, color = C3)) +
  scale_color_identity()+
  geom_jitter() +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: bergant, thank you for your response, this is what I was picturing in my head but unable to bring it to fruition in code.  Thanks again for your time and your solution.